# This function fills my RAM. How to dispose pictures, but so that the return still works?

Tags: vb.net

I use a function that scales an image and returns it. In this function I cannot use `Using`, because otherwise the picture is `Nothing`. Now it is the case that this scaling function is called more often (14 times) and it fills my RAM with garbage. Even after Form2 (where that code is) has closed. How can I get rid of the bitmap that is created in the function every time?

The function scales the original image when a checkbox was clicked, otherwise it returns the original image in its original size.

In the form closing event, it is ensured that all PictureBoxes are emptied. All List (of T) are emptied. So I suspect it must be due to the scaling function.

**in Button1_Click**

```
Using skaliertes_Bitmap As New Bitmap(Bild_sk(Bildpfade1(i)))
```

**the function**

```
Private Function Bild_sk(ByVal path As String) As Bitmap
    Dim Original_Bitmap As New Bitmap(path)
    If CheckBox1.Checked AndAlso (Original_Bitmap.Size.Width <> gew_Breite OrElse Original_Bitmap.Size.Height <> gew_Hoehe) Then
        Dim bitmap1 As New Bitmap(gew_Breite, gew_Hoehe, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        Using Gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1)
            Gr.DrawImage(Original_Bitmap, 0, 0, gew_Breite, gew_Hoehe)
        End Using
        Return bitmap1
    Else
        Return Original_Bitmap
    End If
End Function
```

```
Private Sub Form_auswaehlen_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        If pb.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            pb.Image.Dispose()
        End If
    Next       
End Sub
```

Comment: Inside `Bild_sk`, put `Using Original_Bitmap` inside the `Using Gr As Graphics`. Outside `Bild_sk`, replace `Using skaliertes_Bitmap As New Bitmap(Bild_sk(Bildpfade1(i)))` with `Using skaliertes_Bitmap = Bild_sk(Bildpfade1(i))`.

Comment: Hi @GSerg I did this, a slight improvement. `Using skaliertes_Bitmap = Bild_sk(Bildpfade1(i))` Thank you!!

Comment: However, this is of no use to me in the event that the image should remain in the original. „Inside Bild_sk, put Using Original_Bitmap inside the Using Gr As Graphics.“

Comment: The `Using Gr As Graphics` is inside the branch where you are not returning `Original_Bitmap` so must dispose it. So you *can* put `Using Original_Bitmap` inside the `Using Gr As Graphics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that I didn't write an answer at all. Oh dear. Off the top of my head: You can of course use `Using`, but you have to write `Return New Bitmap(Original_Bitmap)` or `Return New Bitmap(bitmap1)`.